# How can I check if a function is a correct Callable with Python 3.5 type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

I want to do something like this:

```
prototype = typing.Callable[[str, str, typing.Optional[int]], str]

def func(a: str, b: str, c: int=5) -> str:
    return 'foo'

this_is_kosher(func, prototype)  # True
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

Edit for jacob:

Consider:

```
def foo(a: str) -> str:
    return "hello"
```

for me, `this_is_kosher(foo, prototype)` returns True however `prototype` has a 2nd required str parameter.

Comment: I think you may be able to use `inspect.signature(...)` method?